# Any way to pop the Open With dialog on exe files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-association, context-menu

I'm using Windows 7 64Bit SP1.
I want to open `.exe` files with an application (a decompiler, actually). Is there a way to display the `open with` dialog for these files in the right click menu, or something similar?

Comment: The only way I know would break your ability to launch programs, and the way I know, is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me post my answer in case no one comes up with a better one.

The easy way to get functionality that resembles what I'm looking for is to edit the `SendTo` menu. This menu simply displays all the files in the user's `SendTo` folder, and passes the selected file as a command line parameter whenever a SendTo action is chosen.
While this functionality isn't exactly what I'm looking for, it might fit the bill.

All we need to do is navigate to the `SendTo` folder, which in Windows 7 is located in the path `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` and add a shortcut to the program. This won't associate any file extensions with the program; the link will be visible no matter what file we choose. It doesn't involve messing around with the dreaded ***Registry*** though. And, well, now that SendTo menu would become useful for *something* at least.

Comment: I put `Notepad` into my `SendTo` menu, and I find that _very_ useful.

Answer (score 0):

## Context Menu Handlers

The answer you posted to your own question is indeed one way that you could do it.  The method you describe is known as "adding a handler to the context menu" or "creating a context handler".  You can use those terms to do more googling to find further information.

You might prefer to create a custom *context handler* to be a little bit cleaner (i.e. less clicks) in your workflow.  There are a couple of different ways to achieve this- creating a custom entry.

- [Template file](http://www.binaryskeith.com/Projects/MenuTemplate/index.html) for custom context menu entries
- [An article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer) that describe the situation in great detail and offers several approaches
- [Tutorial, source code, and more](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/75560-hacking-windows-xp-hacking-windows-explorer/3) for a tool you can build/enhance yourself

## Using *assoc* and *ftype* Utilities

These are command-line tools that were specifically created to manipulate the handlers/applications designated for each file-type.  First, to explicitly define two terms.  Forgive me if these are already obvious to you.  They seem to cause confusion for most people though.

- *File Extension*- this is the "." plus the 3/4 characters that are found at the end of almost every file assuming MS Windows OS conventions.  The OS may be configured to hide the extension for "known file types", but change that under "folder options". for specific directories or globally across the filesystem.
- *File Type*- Distinct from, but related to, file extensions.  A "file type" encapsulates several file extensions under a single abstraction/concept.  This is a *label*.  It is often the name/pronunciation for its associated extension.  When you see ".txt" you say "textfile".  ".txt" is the extension and "textfile" is the *file type*.

For example, the ".htm" and ".html" **file extensions** are both encapsulated by the "htmlfile" *file type*.  Now for some examples using the *assoc* and *ftype* utilities from the command line.  Open a terminal (Window Key + "R" and a "run" prompt should appear, enter "cmd.exe", click "ok" button or just hit enter).

```
$> assoc .html
.html=htmlfile
$> assoc .htm
.htm=htmlfile
$> ftype htmlfile
htmlfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "%1"
```

These utilities can also be used to assign values to either *extensions* or *file types*.  You can also edit the registry directly or use one of any number of utilities that assist you in manipulating these values.

In your question you specifically mention Open", so I am assuming that you know, at least a little bit, about "verbs" in the context menu.  "Edit" is another common verb.  You probably don't want to override the verb associated with the double-click.  It is perfectly fine to create a new verb called "disasm" and have it show up in the context menu near the top so that R-click->Disasm is a quick process for you to execute.